# Visa questions that don't show research effort

Tags: discussion, good-questions

What do you do with visa related questions([here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48988/how-do-i-get-japan-tourist-visa) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41788/do-i-need-a-visa-for-1-week-holiday-in-istanbul-from-netherlands) for example) that don't show any research ? Other than quote an embassy website or comment with suggestions.

Most embassies/consulates have websites. [This related](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/what-to-do-with-do-i-need-a-visa-questions-lacking-basic-information) question proposes to close as unclear, that doesn't quite apply here as the question is clear but the user hasn't looked before asking.

I feel downvoting new users who may not be familiar with the site wouldn't be a great first experience that invites them to return.

Comment: The main site bestows the higher ups with a "Mjoelnir Hammer" with which some questions can be closed on the spot. Perhaps something like that?  Or alternatively a new close reason: "no initial research"?  You have a good point, I hope it's dealt with.

Comment: Personally I stick with the closing-as-unclear-what-you-are-asking method. I also add a comment specifying why I voted to close, so that my fellow reviewers know what the vote is about. It seems to work for me.

Comment: Anyone want to write that as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Just fielded another one. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50825/do-uk-citizen-required-a-visa-for-vietnam-for-tourist-purpose. Do we need a canonical "how to check if I need a Visa" Question and Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Current solution:**

Close-vote as unclear what you're asking and possibly add a comment

**Suggestion:**

Create a "No initial research" close reason

Comment: We'd be happy to add another close reason, but we are currently using all of the three each SE site gets. Use the default close reason instead.

Answer (score 1):

We'd be happy to add another close reason, but we are currently using all of the three each SE site gets. We should review the usage of our current custom close reasons (I need to collect some stats and I'll write a post about this in the weekend) and then we'll see if we need to update them.

Until then, use the default close reason instead.

Comment: I will, no rush anyway, I was just collecting the comments as an answer