# Should we close all questions which have an answer on Rome2Rio?

Tags: discussion

For example, [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83774/what-are-the-options-of-getting-from-dresden-germany-to-%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD-krumlov-czech-r) about getting from Dresden to Cesky Krumlov has a [perfect answer](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Dresden/%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD-Krumlov) on Rome2Rio. Pretty much any other route between major cities in high-HDI countries will have a good answer there as well.

Should we close all questions such as that one? Maybe even add "Rome2Rio knows the answer" to the list of close reasons?

Comment: Incidentally, I believe it's not possible to *add* a close reason, we can only have five in total. So it would mean replacing one and it's hard to see this as more important than the reasons we already have.

Comment: What do you consider a 'perfect answer'? Going by train from Dresden to Český Krumlov, Rome2Rio is way off both with the duration of travel, ticket price and which trains are going to Český Krumlov at all. Currently, the fastest connection is 6:55 (Rome2Rio says 4:42), ticket prices range from €25-€40 (Rome2Rio says €21-€31), the first train allegedly going from Prague to Český Krumlov, LE1367, actually goes from Prague to Prešov, a completely different direction, and the second train, LE1369, does not exist.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it does show the correct list of *options*: train/bus to Prague + train/bus to Krumlov. Exact schedules are not shown correctly, but they're off-topic on Travel.SE anyway. After researching Rome2Rio OP could then come back and ask how to buy German-Czech railway tickets or where to get the bus tickets, which is a perfectly good question.

Comment: No, it does not. Rome2Rio claims that there are direct trains from Prague to Český Krumlov, which there are not. That other trains are running a similar route, with a necessary change of trains in České Budějovice is just luck and coincidence. I assume that the direct connection listed by Rome2Rio is outdated and not operated anymore. Had there been no alternative, Rome2Rio would now still have listed the outdated connection.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo there *is* a direct train: **Ex 531**, although Rome2Rio is wrong about the train numbers.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, the Ex531 does not run until after the train schedule change next week. Still if it did, it makes absolutely no sense to use it or suggest it if you are looking for a connection from Dresden to Český Krumlov. The Ex531 train will depart Prague 8:02 AM and since the first train from Dresden is not in Prague until 9:27 AM, you would have to spend the night in Prague if you are coming from Dresden and for some reason want to continue with the Ex531.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo hm, maybe Rome2Rio isn't so good then. I think it'd be better to create a canonical about travel within and through Czech Republic, rather than rely on it.

Answer (score 11):

No.  The completeness of Rome2rio varies dramatically based on area.

Comment: Even in high-HDI countries, Rome2Rio is not just often incomplete, but often suggests non-existing means of transport.

Comment: Indeed, r2r still suggests a bus service from LAX to Irvine, California that shut down in 2012, even after I alerted them to that fact weeks ago.

Answer (score 6):

No. There is already an existing mechanism for questions that do not show any research effort - ie down votes.

[Here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/should-showing-zero-research-be-a-close-reason) you seem to have written that lack of research should not be a Close reason.

Comment: Like I said, "A question is either good and within the context of this site or not". If we say that "rome2rio questions" are off-topic, they all can be close-voted.

Comment: a) Google doesn't give you a *direct* answer. Rome2Rio does. b) "the rumba"? c) DCTLib did add a useful bit of information, but it'd be better to have it in a separate question on buying German-Czech rail tickets

Answer (score 5):

No. Even if it were true and the other answers did not apply, why would we want to do that in the first place? After all, we don't close down the whole platform because Quora and Yahoo Answers exist. Conversely, we do not and should not entertain questions merely because no other site will take them.

We have to determine what we want the site to be irrespective of all this and we already have reasonable criteria (WANTA, etc.) to do just that.