# Why was this question on understanding what services self-service transfer kiosks at Amsterdam Schiphol provide closed as unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [Can the self-service transfer kiosks at Amsterdam Schiphol Airport be used even if one hasn't missed a flight or lost one's boarding pass?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178581/1810) was closed because "needs details or clarity". Why? What's unclear or need more details? The  only comment by a close-voter was ~go check out the kiosks by yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simply [sealioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning) and not in search of a real answer to the question it purports to ask.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't seem like a practical, real question you face, but a speculative/fictional scenario like some of your other questions.

Doesn't seem like you have done any research (holding on a phone but not speaking to someone doesn't count).

And you have a number of comments already there describing issues that folks have with the question.

We may not have an exact boilerplate close reason for this type of thing, but I agreed with the other close voters that this was suitable enough.

Comment: 1) "Doesn't seem like a practical, real question you face, but a speculative/fictional scenario" It's a question about some service provided at the  airport, why do you think it is a speculative/fictional scenario?  2) "Doesn't seem like you have done any research (holding on a phone but not speaking to someone doesn't count)." is that a reason to close a question?

Comment: Yeah, it kind of is. We have been round this argument numerous times with you - and remember, to add value here, questions and answers need to be useful to future visitors. That should steer how you approach asking here.

Comment: It's a question about some service provided at the airport, so it is clearly of value to future visitors. Most questions here don't show any research and I don't recall I discussed research requirements on meta (I searched for "research" amongst my questions [and](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385902/178179) the answers they receive, didn't see any results). https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3985/1810 indicates there's no consensus on the need for research beyond closing questions that can be found easily with a Google search, and such questions are almost always left open in practice